# Google Text to Speech Cloud service javascript

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-text-to-speech

I am looking for a guide on how to use google text to speech service in Java script. Currently I am using this:

```
var src = "https://translate.google.com/translate_tts?key='+key +'8&total=1&idx=0&textlen=32&client=tw-ob&q=" + encodeURIComponent(txt) + "&tl=" + language;
    console.log(src)
    var vid = $('#Audio');
    vid.get(0).pause();
    $('#Audio').attr('src', src);
    vid.get(0).load();
    vid.get(0).play();
```

The main issue is that this code is not stable. Sometimes it returns empty audio and sometimes it works for same request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems this service is not added to google-cloud-platform. It was before under google translate but not anymore. using the link in the question will work if there is  user interaction , like pressing a button,. However,calling it dynamically in the code without user interaction will result in an empty audio file. It looks like someway from google to prevent denial of service attack. I ended up using speechSynthesis for languages which are supported in speechSynthesis and third party products for other languages such as Arabic.